# Como definir o timezone no meu arquivo php?

Tags: php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <?php
         $dir = "paginas/";
         $ext = ".php";

         if(isset(S_GET['pagina'])){
           $pagina = ($_GET['pagina']);
         }else{
           $pagina = "inicio";
         }

         if(file_exists($dir.$pagina.$ext)){
           include($dir.$pagina.$ext);
         }else{
           echo "Página não encontrada!";
         }
         ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando fui entrar no meu localhost para ver o arquivo, acabou dando esse erro, tentei definir o timezone no meu arquivo, mas não está funcionando.

Comment: O erro não tem nada a ver com o WARNING. Tens um `S` onde deveria ser `$` na linha 20, em `if(isset(S_GET['pagina'])){`.

Comment: E já agora quando for assim coloque o texto do erro e não a imagem. É mais simples para o ajudarem.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 Passo** - Abra seu arquivo *php.ini*

**2 Passo** - Adicione a seguinte linha de **código** ao topo do seu arquivo *php.ini*: `date.timezone = "US / Central"`

**3 Passo** - Substitua *`US/Central`* pelo fuso horário da **documentação oficial do PHP** que corresponde à hora que você deseja exibir.

**4 Passo** - Salve

**5 Passo** - Reinicie o apache

[Referencia](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file/)

Comment: Muito obrigado :D